# How to continue executing code (pl-sql), after capturing an exception

Tags: oracle11g, exception

I need to continue with the code execution when exception has been captured. 
But my code is exiting when the first exception appeariing, and . 
I try simulate an error, for example when not exists the table from the cursor c1, and never run the second part of the code, where it opens c2.
Cursors c1 and c2 look an intermediate table with the names of the tables then processed in the procedure.

Could you give me any idea?

Thankyou in advanced.

Regards.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ISRREP.isr_retention
IS


   v_count           NUMBER         ;--:= 50;
   v_commit          NUMBER         := 50;
   str_min           VARCHAR2 (100);
   str_del_day       VARCHAR2 (150);
   str_del_month     VARCHAR2 (150);
   str_lastdate      VARCHAR2 (150);
   v_lastdate        DATE;
   v_lastdate_fin    DATE;
   str_min_fin       VARCHAR2 (100);
   v_hay_registros   NUMBER         ; --:= 1;
   errno             NUMBER;
   errmsg            VARCHAR2 (255);
   str_error         VARCHAR2 (300);
   str_upd_err       VARCHAR2 (300);
   v_table1          VARCHAR2 (50);
   v_table2          VARCHAR2 (50);
   v_table3          VARCHAR2 (50);
   v_table4          VARCHAR2 (50);
   v_table5          VARCHAR2 (50);

   /* armo cursor */
   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT   ID, activeflag, errormessage, tablename, retention,
               retentionunit, lastdate
          FROM isrfrequency_sacme
         WHERE activeflag = 'ACTIVE'
         AND retentionunit = 'Month'
      ORDER BY tablename;

       CURSOR c2
   IS
      SELECT   ID, activeflag, errormessage, tablename, retention,
               retentionunit, lastdate
          FROM isrfrequency_sacme
         WHERE activeflag = 'ACTIVE'
         AND retentionunit = 'Day'
      ORDER BY tablename;  

   r1                c1%ROWTYPE;
   r2                c2%ROWTYPE;

    BEGIN


           OPEN c1;


               LOOP
                  FETCH c1
                   INTO r1;

                  EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;



                  str_min := 'select min(utctime) from ' || r1.tablename;          --Obtengo fecha y hora mas antigua

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_min INTO v_lastdate;


                      --Tablas con retencionunit Month

                      BEGIN

                       r1.retentionunit := 'Month';

                                 str_del_month := 'delete '|| r1.tablename    
                                    || ' where UTCTIME < ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-' --|| ' where UTCTIME < trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-'
                                    || r1.RETENTION
                                    || ')';                                    --Delete de registros que exceden la retencion


                                 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_del_month;

                                 v_table1 := r1.tablename;

                                 v_hay_registros := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

                                     IF v_hay_registros != 0
                                     THEN
                                        COMMIT;

                                     END IF;

                                 str_min_fin := 'select min(utctime) from ' || r1.tablename;                        --Obtengo nuevamente fecha y hora mas antigua

                                 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_min_fin INTO v_lastdate_fin;

                                 str_lastdate :=
                                       'update ISRFREQUENCY_SACME set LASTDATE = TO_DATE('''
                                    || v_lastdate_fin
                                    || ''',''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'') where tablename = '''
                                    || r1.tablename
                                    || '''';                                                                       --Update en tabla ISRFREQUENCY_SACME con el ultimo valor leido

                                 --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (str_lastdate);

                                 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_lastdate;


                                --
                                -- EXEPCIONES PARCIALES
                                --
                          EXCEPTION
                          WHEN OTHERS
                          THEN
                                   errno := SQLCODE;
                                   errmsg := SQLERRM;

                                test_debug.p_test_debug_out ('ISR_RETENTION', errmsg, 'NO');

                                update isrfrequency_sacme set activeflag = 'ERROR', errormessage = errmsg  where tablename = r1.tablename;
                                commit;

                                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'ERROR: '|| errmsg || '. ISRFREQUENCY_SACME.MESSAGGE');
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');

                                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Se ha producido una excepción.');
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error code: ' || SQLCODE);
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error message: ' || SQLERRM);


                          END;                               

               END LOOP;    

            CLOSE c1;       



                              --Tablas con retencionunit Day      

            OPEN c2;


               LOOP
                  FETCH c2
                   INTO r2;

                  EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;


                      BEGIN

                              r1.retentionunit := 'Day';

                                 str_del_day :=
                                       'delete '
                                    || r2.tablename
                                    || ' where UTCTIME < trunc(sysdate-'
                                    || r2.RETENTION
                                    || ')';                                                              --Delete de registros que exceden la retencion




                                 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_del_day;


                                 v_table2 := r2.tablename;

                                 v_hay_registros := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
                                 --v_hay_registros := v_count;

                                     IF v_hay_registros != 0
                                     --IF v_count != 0

                                     THEN
                                        COMMIT;


                                     ELSE

                                     END IF;

                                 str_min_fin := 'select min(utctime) from ' || r2.tablename;                                   --Obtengo nuevamente fecha y hora mas antigua

                                 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_min_fin INTO v_lastdate_fin;


                                 str_lastdate :=
                                       'update ISRFREQUENCY_SACME set LASTDATE = TO_DATE('''
                                    || v_lastdate_fin
                                    || ''',''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'') where tablename = '''
                                    || r2.tablename
                                    || '''';                                                           --Update en tabla ISRFREQUENCY_SACME con el ultimo valor UTCTIME, luego del delete

                                 --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (str_lastdate);

                                 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_lastdate;


                              --
                              -- EXEPCIONES PARCIALES
                              --
                                EXCEPTION
                                WHEN OTHERS
                                THEN
                                        errno := SQLCODE;
                                        errmsg := SQLERRM;

                                test_debug.p_test_debug_out ('ISR_RETENTION', errmsg, 'NO');

                                update isrfrequency_sacme set activeflag = 'ERROR', errormessage = errmsg  where tablename = r2.tablename;
                                commit;

                                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'ERROR: '|| errmsg || '. ISRFREQUENCY_SACME.MESSAGGE');
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');

                                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Se ha producido una excepción.');
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error code: ' || SQLCODE);
                                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error message: ' || SQLERRM);

                                --NULL;

                                END;


               END LOOP;

       CLOSE c2;


    --
    -- EXEPCIONES FINALES
    --
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
          errno := SQLCODE;
          errmsg := SQLERRM;

          test_debug.p_test_debug_out ('ISR_RETENTION', errmsg, 'NO');

          update isrfrequency_sacme set activeflag = 'ERROR', errormessage = errmsg  where tablename = r1.tablename;
          commit;

          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'ERROR: '|| errmsg || '. ISRFREQUENCY_SACME.MESSAGGE');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++');

          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Se ha producido una excepción.');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error code: ' || SQLCODE);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error message: ' || SQLERRM);

    END;   

/
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Your description isn't particularly clear but it sounds like you are creating a compilation error.  If the procedure doesn't compile successfully, no part of it can execute.  No exception handler can catch a compilation error (in static SQL).

Comment: Isn't a compilation error. The error captured is:                                {ISR_RETENTION: ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe}                      when c1 didn't found the table name. 
The procedure is compiled OK

Comment: An ORA-00942 error would normally be a compilation error.  If you're getting that as a runtime error, it must be coming from one of the many dynamic SQL statements you are executing.  Which specific dynamic SQL statement is failing?

Comment: c1 is searching a list of tables. 
One of them does not exists, because I rename her temporarily. 
Then the error is 'ORA-00942', but I need that the code continues with what follows, that is to c2.
Is it posible or I must try simulate other kind of error?

Comment: Which of the various dynamic SQL statements is failing?  You'd need an exception handler around that dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: str_del_month  fails

Comment: If `execute immediate str_del_month` throws an exception, that exception would be caught by the exception handler in the `c1` loop.  Based on the text of your question, that appears to be what you want to happen.

Comment: Yes Justin, but I need that the code continues with what follows, that is to c2. Is it posible ?

Comment: The code you posted appears to do that.  Or I am not understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  The code you posted will continue with the next iteration of `c1` (I'm assuming that your formatting is generally indicative of the level of nesting that you actually have).  Are you saying that you want to stop iterating through `c1` at the point that an exception is encountered and start iterating through `c2` rather than continuing with `c1`?  If so, you're probably missing a `break` statement in your exception handler.

Comment: I need to continue with the c2 iteration, executing  str_del_day (see the code). But right now, the exception found with str_del_month is captured, and the code ends.

Comment: I'm not following.  Possibly my problem is that you've posted quite a bit of code but haven't reduced the problem to a simple, complete test case that reproduces the issue.

Comment: no problem, thanks anyway.